# CSS Drop Down Menu behind JQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, css, menu, jquery-ui-dialog

The drop down menu is currently showing behind the JQuery dialog box.  I'd like to show the drop down menu in front of the dialog box.  I tried to change the z-index, but no luck.

```
$( function() {
  $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog({
    appendTo: $("#bodyContent")
  });
} );
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/john12345/ofrhodpv/

Thank you!

Comment: Which z-index did you try to change? Probalby the wrong one. The jQuery-UI creates it's own new element (`.ui-dialog.ui-widget`) for the dialog with: `z-index: 1001;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dialog box has a  `z-index: 1003;` so to overlap it you need to give the dropdown menu a bigger value more than 1003

[**see demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ofrhodpv/2/)